# How can I give a network load balancer (of any type) access to a port on a machine without opening that port to an entire VPC?

Tags: firewalls, aws

Is it possible to make an AWS load balancer for a non-HTTP port allowed to access a specific port on a host without opening that port open to the entire VPC's subnet? I seem to remember reading that this might be possible with an IAM policy based around specific resources or something like that.

As you create a non-classic network load balancer it says:
" The security groups for your instances must allow traffic from the VPC CIDR on the health check port."

Which is ok, but just barely since this service really doesn't have much/any authentication.

Isn't there a way this can be done with IAM permissions instead of a security group? I was reading about AWS WAF security somewhere and they mentioned that sometimes you can use an IAM policy, sometimes even a cross-account IAM policy to connect to the machines behind the WAF.

Any suggestions? I can definitely deploy more machines or AWS stuff.

Comment: Would this be completely pointless because I can't restrict access to the network ELB?

Comment: Could I add a firewall in front of the ELB to restrict access to that? What should I be reading about?